# Laptop and 2 external monitors

Tags: laptop, external-display

I have an HP Pavilion Gaming laptop (ec2088ax) and I want to connect 2 external monitors to it for work.

I bought multiple adapters from USB-C to USB-A, with and without drivers with no success.

I bought an HDMI switch but it only duplicates the 3rd monitor from the 2nd one and doesn't extend it.

I plan to buy a Type C docking station or an HDMI docking station but I am afraid it won't work.

Can anybody help with this? I don't want to replace my laptop since it was very expensive when I bout it and all my files are there.

If by any chance the ports are not compatible, is there an option to connect a docking station to allow 2 external monitors to be extended from the main monitor of the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the required HDMI graphics outputs for two monitors but the inbuilt graphics on your laptop are fairly powerful and should easily be able to power 2 additional monitors.

[This spec suggest USB ports on your laptop support don't support graphics output](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c07970877#AbT0) but [this one is ambiguous](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c07970877#AbT0).

Could try some of the following:

1. Buy a single larger, wider monitor that gives you the amount of screen area that you need
2. Try a USB-C input monitor to test your USB-C port to see if provides graphics output. If this works, you can have one on USB-C and one on HDMI.

Comment: I tried USB C but it doesnt support ALT D or Thunderbolt and it doesnt show any display. Im thinking of getting an HDMI dockling station but I am too anxious to try coz it's getting pretty expensive and unsure if it will work.